# Error parsing when openning new terminal on mac

Tags: macos, terminal

when i open a new terminal on my mac i get the following error:

```
-bash: /etc/profile: line 12: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /etc/profile: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like your `/etc/profile` startup script is corrupted somehow.  What are the contents of that file?

Comment: I dont even remember, how can i access it to find out its contents?

Comment: Solved the file was missing a "

Comment: Funny, that's exactly what the error was telling you ;O)